# Can I bundle the Oracle JDBC driver JAR in a Docker image?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, docker

I'm building Docker images based on the [official Docker Tomcat images](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/tomcat/), where in addition to Tomcat, I add one of our web applications as a WAR file so it gets deployed when the container starts.

Since the application requires access to a database, and the supported databases use different JDBC drivers and some additional configuration files, I'm building one image per supported database (all based on a common base image), where the image contains the respective database configuration and JDBC driver JAR.

So far, I have done this for MySQL and PostgreSQL, and I'm now looking at support for Oracle.

Since Oracle is a commercial product, and I read somewhere (sorry, no official source) that you're not allowed to bundle the JDBC drivers - what's the best solution for this?

Am I permitted/allowed to bundle the Oracle JDBC driver JAR in a Docker image that I make available to our internal users (not outside of the company)? Or do I have to ask users to download the driver themselves and map it into the image?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question but a request for legal advice.

Comment: Just all questions about Docker practices are off-topic (related to DevOps but not to programming). Most people think they desserve to stay open though. Maybe the SO rules would need some "DevOps" opening ?

Comment: @Tristan this is not about DevOps or not. It's about asking for legal advice. You are not a qualified IP lawyer (I assume). Your answer (and any other answer given to this question) is not based on expertise but rather on a layman's interpretation of a legal document. StackOverflow should remain a source for *programming* expertise. See [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing).

Answer (score 2):

When you need an Oracle jdbc driver inside a war, you provide the service for your users without asking Oracle and without asking your users to accept the license, so it should not be different for a Docker image.

Now if you are distributing the driver packaged into your own software (not only the service), I guess Oracle requires you to contact them :

"**Can third party vendors distribute Oracle's JDBC drivers along with their own software?**

If you are a third party software company (and Oracle partner) then please check out Oracle's licensing terms spelled out at Oracle Licensing Agreement Please contact your local Oracle sales rep for more details."

source : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html